# How to display PDF link in SXA

Tags: sxa, pdf

I'm using Sitecore 9.1 and SXA 1.8.

I have a few PDF files in my website.

How to implement PDF Download in SXA
(Sitecore fields **Description-Text and PDF-Link**)?

When visitor clicks **Description-Text** in the browser, the PDF will be downloaded at Browser.

Please suggest me

Comment: Not sure which SXA component you are using , but you can easily use the Promo component and add a link to the PDF stored in Media library. Clicking the Link description would download the PDF on browser, this is OOTB functionality

Comment: There are couple of OOTB components in SXA that support this functionaity. Take a look on Link or Link List or File List or Media Link